# Turtle Module in python not importing

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

this is my fist time using the turtle module in python but i can't seem to import it?
Here's my code:

```
from turtle import *

pen1 = Pen()
pen2 = Pen()

pen1.screen.bgcolour("#2928A7")
```

and here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Python saves\turtle.py", line 2, in <module>
    from turtle import *
  File "C:\Python34\Python saves\turtle.py", line 5, in <module>
    pen1 = Pen()
NameError: name 'Pen' is not defined
```

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: It looks like `turtle.py` is the name of your program. Is that correct?

Comment: I think you actually want to use `pen` not `Pen`, also I don't think you can store multiple pens as objects.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: Probably; it's a bit confusing, since `Pen` is an alias for the `Turtle` class.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah, and if you could store multiple pens as classes it would make sense to be a capital P, but the docs suggest that instead `pen()` is a function for interacting with the attributes of the only pen that exists.

Comment: `Pen` (not `pen`) is the thing to do in this context.  Naming your own source file `turtle.py` is not the thing to do.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36250353/4014959

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you've named your program "turtle.py".

So when Python sees the statement
`from turtle import *`
the first matching module named `turtle` that it finds is *your* program, "turtle.py".

In other words, your program is basically importing itself and *not* the turtle graphics module.

---

Here's some code to demonstrate this problem.

**turtle.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' Mock Turtle

    Demonstrate what happens when you give your program the same name
    as a module you want to import.

    See http://stackoverflow.com/q/32180949/4014959

    Written by PM 2Ring 2015.08.24
'''

import turtle

foo = 42
print(turtle.foo)
help(turtle)
```

---

I guess I should show what that code actually prints...

When run as `turtle.py` it prints the following "help" info:

```
Help on module turtle:

NAME
    turtle - Mock Turtle

FILE
    /mnt/sda4/PM2Ring/Documents/python/turtle.py

DESCRIPTION
    Demonstrate what happens when you give your program the same name
    as a module you want to import.

    See http://stackoverflow.com/q/32180949/4014959

    Written by PM 2Ring 2015.08.24

DATA
    foo = 42

(END)
```

When you hit `Q` to get out of the Help, the Help info is displayed again. When you hit `Q` for the second time, then

```
42

42
```

is printed.

Why are the "help" message and 42 printed twice? That's because all the code in `turtle.py` is executed when it's imported, and then again when its encountered *after* the `import` statement. Note that Python doesn't try to import modules that it has already imported (unless explicitly told to do so with `reload`). If Python *did* re-import, then the above code would get stuck in an infinite loop of importing.

---

When run as `mockturtle.py` it prints:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mock_turtle.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(turtle.foo)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

And of course that's because the standard `turtle` module doesn't actually have a `foo` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

I think the solution is to type this :

```
pen1 = turtle.Pen()
```