# Python beginner. name 'crypt' is not defined

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am reading about the crypt() function for UNIX passwords.

```
import crypt
crypt.crypt("egg","HX")
```

Here is what I get after running my program

```
File "...", line 2, in <module> crypt.crypt("egg","HX")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I've read several posts on google and stackOverflow and found that I have to import the library so:

```
from crypt import *
crypt.crypt("egg","HX")
```

but now I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "crypt.py", line 1, in <module>
from crypt import *
File "...", line 2, in <module>
crypt.crypt("egg","HX")
NameError: name 'crypt' is not defined
```

How can this error be resolved? And what is the difference between

```
import smth
```

and

```
from smth import smth1?
```

Thank you!

Comment: which OS you are using?

Comment: I'm using macOS Sierra

Comment: The problem is that you named your program `crypt.py`. So when it does `import crypt` it imports _itself_.

Comment: add it as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted

Comment: The question I linked talks about the `requests` module, but it's the _exact same thing_ that's happening for you with the `crypt` module: you gave your program the same name as the module you're trying to import, and Python finds your program first before it finds the other module with the same name.

Comment: You may also like to take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32180949/turtle-module-in-python-not-importing) on this topic, which I wrote before my friend idjaw wrote the question & answer I linked above.